# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class - Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

So I have seen other articles here on stack about this and a lot of the time people are not doing @post = post.new. I read some where to use the plural...??

any ways I am getting this error on my discussion code:

**Model**

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
  belongs_to :author
  attr_accessible :author_id, :content, :title

  validate :comment, :presence => true
  validate :title, :presence => true
end
```

**Discussion Controller**

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @discussion = Discussion.new
    @discussions = Discussion.all
  end

  def create
    @discussion = Discussion.create(params[:discussion])
    if @discussion.save
      redirect_to tasks_path, :flash => {:success => 'Created a new discussion'}
    else
      redirect_to tasks_path, :flash => {:error => 'Failed to create a discussion'}
    end
  end
end
```

**Discussion Form**

```
<%= form_for @discussion do |f| %>

    <p><%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %></p>

    <p><%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %></p>

<% end %>
```

**Discussion Routes**

```
  resources :discussions do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Now as far as I know I am doing this right, because I have a task form set up essentially the same way - but I have looked at my code for hours and have googled and tried other examples and now i see this:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @discussion do |f| %>
2: 
3:  <p><%= f.label :title %>
4:  <%= f.text_field :title %></p>
```

Which should mean that I am missing something from my controller.....is it as asilly as a spelling mistake? >.>

Comment: where did u get the code from? can you paste the controller please?

Comment: Have you copy-pasted your code here verbatim? That is, might you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: I wrote the code, that is the entire controller. all code here has been copy and pasted verbatim. I can add the model if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are trying to create a discussion on a task form but have only defined the discussion controller and not the task controller.

Comment: No. thats not it. The task form works for creating, editing, deleting. its the discussion form that wont render. the task form has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting this in your discussion controller?

```
def new
  @discussion = Discussion.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to add :method => :post to the form for creating the object else the form will get submitted with GET request.

```
<%= form_for @discussion , :method => :post do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the **index view** that has the form_for?

If not, then you should add a **new** action to the controller and do `@discussion = Discussion.new` there and not in your **index** action.

Answer (score 0):

if ur model relationships are exactly as u have provided, then they are incorrect

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment #has_many :comments
  belongs_to :author
  attr_accessible :author_id, :content, :title

  validate :comment, :presence => true #valide :comments, :presence => true
  validate :title, :presence => true
end
```